# IF ElementID value then change another ElementID value

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to lookup a field's value, if it equals '1', then put the value '1' in different field, if not put a '0'.

I'm not sure why this isn't working, can anyone help?

```
<input type="text" name="_1_1_33_1_id" value="" onchange="checkLineManager();">
<input class="valueeditable" type="text" name="_1_1_118_1" id="_1_1_118_1" value="" >
```

Javascript:

```
function checkLineManager() {
if (document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id').value == '1') {
    document.getElementById('_1_1_118_1').value = '1';
} else {
    document.getElementById('_1_1_118_1').value = '0';
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nbren007/o9xp0efy/

Comment: `getElementsByName()` returns an array, so you would need to select the one you want first before checking its `value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the plural use of "elements" in the following line:

```
if (document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id').value == '1') {
```

This doesn't return an element, it returns a node list.

```
// To confirm that
alert(document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id').toString());
```

So you need to use:

```
if (document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id')[0].value == '1') {
```

There are other ways of accessing the element as well. Most notably through the `form` `element` approach.

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in the method: `getElementsByName` returns more than one element - it returns an array of matching elements.

You need to use array notation to select the element from the array.

Change:

```
document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id')
```

To:

```
document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id')[0]
```

---

```
if (document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id')[0].value == '1') {
    document.getElementById('_1_1_118_1').value = '1';
} else {
    document.getElementById('_1_1_118_1').value = '0';
}
```

Or even neater, use a [ternary statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
document.getElementById('_1_1_118_1').value =
    document.getElementsByName('_1_1_33_1_id')[0].value == 1 ? '1' : '0';
```

Comment: or better yet give your elements an `id` as well as a `name`, and then use `getElementById()`.  Use the name for form parameter passing, the ID for DOM manipulation.

Comment: Note: It return a *NODE LIST*, which is array-like in that it has integer properties and a `length` property, but it isn't an array. You can't push/pop/sort.